# Add up Variables by Mouse Actions

Tags: java, swing, addition

I'm just about done creating a application that takes a simple pizza order /w topping, and then shows the order in a text field. However, I'm not sure how to tell the program what was selected and ***then add up what was selected***. I tried different methods, but I'm not getting the result I was hoping for.

Could someone provide assistance?

```
    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void pSmallActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
         int Small;
        Small = 8;

    }                                      

    private void pLargeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        int Large;
        Large = 12;
    }                                      

    private void totalFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           



    }                                          

    private void pMedActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        int Med;
        Med = 10;
    }                                    

    private void pChkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        boolean jCheckBox1ActionPerformed = false;
        if (jCheckBox1ActionPerformed) { 
            int pep;
            pep = 1;
        } else {

        } 

    }                                    

    private void sChkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
           boolean jCheckBox1ActionPerformed = false;
        if (jCheckBox1ActionPerformed) { 
            int sus;
            sus = 1;
        } else {

        } 
    }                                    

    private void mChkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
           boolean jCheckBox1ActionPerformed = false;
        if (jCheckBox1ActionPerformed) { 
            int mus;
            mus = 1;
        } else {

        } 
    }                                    

    private void oChkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
           boolean jCheckBox1ActionPerformed = false;
        if (jCheckBox1ActionPerformed) { 
            int oin;
            oin = 1;
        } else {

        } 
    }                                    

    private void Test(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                      

       int Large = 12;
        int Med = 10;
        int Small = 8;
        int mus = 1;
        int oin = 1;
        int pep = 1;
        int sus = 1;
        Integer.toString (Large);
        Integer.toString (Med);
        Integer.toString (Small);
        Integer.toString (mus);
        Integer.toString (oin);
        Integer.toString (pep);
        Integer.toString (sus);
        int total = Small + Large + Med + pep + sus + mus + oin;
        String total2 = String.valueOf(total);
        totalField.setText(total2);


    }                     

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(pizzaMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(pizzaMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(pizzaMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(pizzaMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new pizzaMenu().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    public javax.swing.JCheckBox mChk;
    public javax.swing.JCheckBox oChk;
    public javax.swing.JCheckBox pChk;
    public javax.swing.JRadioButton pLarge;
    public javax.swing.JRadioButton pMed;
    public javax.swing.JRadioButton pSmall;
    public javax.swing.JCheckBox sChk;
    public javax.swing.JTextField totalField;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: *"Could someone provide assistance?"*  Not at this general a level.  That's what a personal tutor is for, and SO is not set up to find them.  *"but I'm not getting the result I was hoping for."*  What result were you hoping for?  What is the calculated result given?  -- For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). And I mean an MCVE as opposed to 463 lines of uncompilable code snippet..

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that